# Yeoman + EmberJS + Phonegap

Tags: cordova, ember.js, yeoman

I'm currently developing an app using yeoman + EmberJS.
So i'm decided to deploy it on the IOS and Android using Phonegap.

**So how do we wrap a 'prebuilt' yeoman + ember project in Phonegap?**

I tried using [phonegap build](http://phonegap.com/) but according to the [document](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_getting_started.md.html#configure_application), there is a requirement in building the structure. So the *android.apk* I've downloaded won't work.

And theres no yeoman generator with this 3 combos.

Comment: You might want to see how [ember-cli-cordova](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-cordova) does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't the best method but at least it's working.

I manually copy the 'compiled-templates.js' and 'combined-scripts.js' generated by grunt and copy all the dependencies to the newly created phonegap project.

Include all the files in the index.html, and use "phonegap build ios" in terminal to generate an xCode file and finally deploy to the ios platform through xCode.

ps:
*compiled-templates.js contain all the Ember.js templates.

combined-scripts.js contain all the javascripts.*